# Flickering colors while hovering css

Tags: html, css, hover, flicker

I'm trying to use a background image over a semi-transparent div element, where hovering over either one changes the background color. However, I'm encountering a flickering effect when moving my mouse over either element.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="first box"></div>
  <div class="third box">third</div>
  <div class="second box">second</div>
  <div class="fourth box">fourth</div>
  <div class="last box">last</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, 
.container {
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

.box {
    width: 191px;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}

.box:hover{
    background-color:#EF6939;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:hover{
    background-color:#EF6939;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
    width: 191px;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    /*  background-image: url(test.png);*/
}

.first {
    /* float: left; */
    /* background-color: red; */
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.second{
    /*     float: left;*/    
    /* background-color: green; */
}

.third{
    /* float: right; */
    /*  background-color: blue; */
}

.fourth {
    /* float: right; */
    /*  background-color: #DDDDDD; */
}

.last{
    /* float: right; */
    /*  background-color: yellow; */
}
```

Here is a link to my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YTDyL/

Comment: What purpose does div.test serve? The problem is its overlapping div.first because it's positioned absolutely. Probably need to move div.test inside div.first (or vice versa). Both elements are competing for :hover, since they overlap. http://jsfiddle.net/YTDyL/1/

Comment: You should put that as the answer

Comment: You should put that as the answer

Comment: Yep thats the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What purpose does `div.test` serve?

The problem is it's overlapping `div.first` because it's positioned absolutely. Depending on your desired effect, you probably need to move `div.test` inside `div.first` (or vice versa). Whichever will be the container needs to  be positioned (relative or absolute or otherwise) if it will hold a `position: absolute;` element.

Both elements are competing for `:hover`, since they overlap. Thus the flicker (as one gains and the other loses `:hover`, and back again, upon mouse movement).

[jsfiddle.net/YTDyL/1](http://jsfiddle.net/YTDyL/1)

Comment: Why not just put your jsFiddle in the answer?

Comment: It wouldn't let me link to fiddle without embedded code... never seen that before on SO. New feature?

Comment: Oh yeah... it's to curb the over-use of jsFiddle links in place of  making fully "self-contained" answers.  You should still post the code of your solution... then it will allow your jsFiddle demo link as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm. Also thanks for the very quick responses.

Answer (score 3):

It is flickering when you move the pointer over the elements since they are having the same z-index and so both hover effect are triggering. If you add `z-index` attributes to both elements so one has a higher index then the other one, the flickering will not occur.

Here is a fiddle for you to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/YTDyL/3/

Answer (score 2):

add z-index to `.test`

```
.test{z-index:99;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBhV5/)